# What could make a ROS package terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'?

Tags: c++, ros, px4

this question might be better suited for px4 forums, but no one replies there.

When I try to launch a particular node/module for ROS using a launch file on jetson TX2, it terminates and shows this error,

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
[local_planner_node-2] process has died [pid 20132, exit code -6, cmd /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib/local_planner/local_planner_node __name:=local_planner_node __log:=/home/user/.ros/log/80e889fe-d9b5-11eb-8fd5-48b02d0f174f/local_planner_node-2.log].
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/80e889fe-d9b5-11eb-8fd5-48b02d0f174f/local_planner_node-2*.log
```

the same package with the same launch file works on my intel laptop, both have the same ros melodic installed, and both have ubuntu 18.04 installed. (laptop 18.04.5, Jetson 18.04.3).

I understand that this might be a setup/environment problem, but i am not able to determine the difference.

Log files, launch file, and terminal outputs can be seen [here](https://github.com/PX4/PX4-Avoidance/issues/651).

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The error is caused by passing `NULL` into `std::string`s constructor.  Why this happened is unknown as we need to see a [mcve].

Comment: It was the wrong version of CMAKE, that caused errors in find .. code. that caused null to be passed to a string variable.